How to get my Solana to usd On my card
I’m trying to transfer the money on my Solana to my bank but I don’t know how to.

Probably the easiest way is to transfer to a centralized exchange like Coinbase or Gemini, convert the solana to usd, and then ach fiat withdraw to your bank account.
